# Centering responsive content in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a fixed (span12) container. Within that I have a span3 sidebar, and a span9 content area.

Within the span9 content area, I have 2 images. I want them to split 50/50, and still be responsive, so that when my screen is huge, they span the full width of the content area, and yet when they are resized to be in a 1024 area, they shrink, not wrap.

Here's my working example, but with span5 and a span4 thumbnails. How do I get 50/50, so basically span4.5 ?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/240752/custom/test.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `row-fluid` to nest a 12-column layout in your `span9`

```
<div class="span9">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't split span9 itno 4 and 5 ... split it to 2 span6 and it will display correctly

Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/eMETn/